# Ruby equivalent of C++ istream operator?

Tags: ruby

With Ruby, I'd like to read and operate on integers one-at-a-time from STDIN.  There are multiple lines of space separated integers:

```
3 67 41 20
6 21 433 25 1 6
5 2 3 5
```

In C++, the `istream::operator>>` automatically skips past whitespace, whether it's a space or a newline, and successively reads all the integers:

```
cin >> val;
foo(val);
```

In Ruby, the best I can find is this, which gets caught at the end of a line:

```
val = gets(' ')
```

I've also tried `scanf.rb`, but that seems to read a single integer and then discard the rest of the line:

```
require 'scanf.rb'
N.times do
  p scanf("%d")
end
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

I know no operator that works that way, so I would do it like that, not the best answer but still one.

```
result=[]
while input = gets do
  input.split(' ').each do |value|
    result << value.chomp
  end
end
```